# Function member as parameter of CUDA kernel

Tags: c++, cuda

I am working with dynamic parallelism and I would like to create a template kernel that given an object pointer + member function pointer execute the function. This is a minimum (not) working example, compiled with -arch=compute_35 -dlink flags,

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    int i;
    __device__ void clear()
    {
        i = 0;
    }
};

template<typename Object, typename memberFunction>
__global__ void generalKernel(Object* o, memberFunction f)
{
    (o->*f)();
}

template<typename Object, typename memberFunction>
__device__ void executeFunction(Object* o, memberFunction f)
{
    generalKernel<<<1,1>>>(o,f);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
}

__global__ void mainKernel(A* a)
{
    executeFunction(a, &A::clear);
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    A* a;
    cudaMallocManaged(&a, sizeof(A));
    a->i = 1;

    mainKernel<<<1,1>>>(a);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    std::cout << a->i << std::endl;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: please provide a short, complete example, that someone else could try to compile and see the issue.  also identify your compile command and the exact output of the compiler

Comment: Updated with a complete example :). The error is pretty long to provide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple CUDA code, to show how to pass member function pointers to kernel. Everything is explained in the code.

```
#define gpuErrchk(val) \
    cudaErrorCheck(val, __FILE__, __LINE__, true)
void cudaErrorCheck(cudaError_t err, char* file, int line, bool abort)
{
    if(err != cudaSuccess)
    {
        printf("%s %s %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(err), file, line);
        if(abort) exit(-1);
    }
}


// struct holds an 'int' type data memeber and '__device__' function member
struct ST
{
    int id;
    __device__ void foo()
    {
        printf("value of id: %d\n",id);
    }
};

// creating an alias for our function pointer
// since the function is a member of a struct, we add struct name and scope resolution 'ST::'
// to signify as such
typedef void (ST::*Fptr)(void);

// templated kernel
template<typename Object, typename memberFunction>
__global__ void kernel(Object* o, memberFunction f)
{
   (o->*f)();
}

// declaring a __device__ function pointer, assigning it the address of 'ST::foo' 
// remember that this function pointer is also direclty accessible from the kernel
__device__ Fptr fp = &ST::foo;


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    // declaring and initializing a host 'ST' object
    ST h_st;
    h_st.id = 10;


    // device 'ST' object
    ST* d_st;
    // allocating device memory
    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_st, sizeof(ST)));
    // copying host data from host object to device object
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_st, &h_st, sizeof(ST), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

    // declaring host side function pointer of type 'Fptr', which can be passed to kernel as argument
    Fptr h_fptr;
    // copying address of '__device__' function pointer to host side function pointer
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpyFromSymbol(&h_fptr, fp, sizeof(Fptr)));


    // passing arguments to kernel
    kernel<<<1,1>>>(d_st,h_fptr);

    // making sure no errors occured
    gpuErrchk(cudaPeekAtLastError());
    gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceSynchronize());

    // free device memory
    gpuErrchk(cudaFree(d_st));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I was looking for a one-fit-all solution, that is why I used template. Typedef function pointer and declare it each time is worst to code than create a kernel for each function to call.

Comment: read this for how best to use function pointers https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members

Comment: I managed to compile using identifier alias. The issue is now related to unified memory like in this case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42296854/assignment-of-function-pointer-with-the-unified-memory-in-cuda. I leave this idea and will find another one.